# Connecting to a mock data set using the MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am experimenting with building an application using the M.E.A.N stack. I've managed to get as far as setting up a test page and successfully utilizing Angular.js' ability to display and re-order data based upon search criteria. I am interested in taking it a small step further by calling upon data stored in an external Json document using a javascript controller. When I run the program as is everything checks out okay except for one thing; I can't seem to properly link the file. I think I may not fully understand which document is meant to be treated as the root file.

My code is as fallows:

Controller.js:

```js
var phonecatApp = angular.module('contactApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('ContactListCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,
    $http) {
    $http.get('../data/contacts.json').success(
      function(data) {
        $scope.contacts = data;
  });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
  }]);
```

My File structure is as follows:

```
myApp
├── data
|   |-- contacts.json
├── public
│   ├── javascripts
│   │   ├── controllers
|           |---controller.js
|---views
|   |---index.jade
|   |---layout.jade
```

What iv'e tried:

I read through the documentation and I believe it instructed me to write the link in my to my controller as if it were coming from the index.jade file. However, this didn't seem to work out the way I wanted.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the Node.js part of code where you set the static directories (you probably use Express so check this http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html), perhaps it is the `public` one, so move `data` into public and refer it as `$http.get('/data/contacts.json')`

Comment: Thanks a million! Worked like a charm. Thanks for linking that documentation as well, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I attempted to use the same method for loading an image into the view via an (imgUrl:) link in the json file and was unsuccessful. Is there something i'm missing here as well? Sorry, and thank you.

Comment: Use ng-src in the html to load the value

Comment: Thank you once again. I have to say Angular has a lot of confusing quarks but it really is one the most amazing dev tool i've used so far.

Comment: I agree you need only some practical experience on it keep up learning it :)